# How to receive the arguments in python sub process runnable file

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', downloadscript.py, "--longitude", long, "--latitude", lat, "--download_to", ],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I want to get the `longitude`, `latitude` and `download_to` in `downloadscript.py` file

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd='python downloadscript.py --longitude "{lo}" --latitude "{la}" --download_to "{d}"'\
.format(lo=long,la=latitude,d=down_to)
subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Assuming you set a convention of -arg_name arg_value,

You can use this snippet in your `downloadscript.py` file:

```
import sys
k=''
args={}
for a in sys.argv:
    if a.startswith('-'):
        k=a.replace('-','')
        continue
    args[k]=a
print (args)# {longitude:'value',latitude:'value',download_to:'value'}
```

If you are using python 2.7 or above, you can use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module.

(Note that the default python version for many common linux distributions is 2.6.x)

Answer (score 0):

The most pythonic way to parse arguments in Python is the module `argparse`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("longitude", help="enter longitude")
parser.add_argument("latitude", help="enter latitude")
parser.add_argument("download_to", help="target directory")

args = parser.parse_args()
latitude = args.latitude
```

Read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html